# Data from ItemsSource - Textwrapping in a ListView

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

So, I cannot figure out how to get data from a SQL data-set to be viewed in a TextWrapping-typed format for ListView's. Remember, I'm not hard-coding in strings/data, it's all grabbed by the ItemSource bindings from a data-set.

Example of said data:
[image: Data Example]

Example of how my entire window looks atm:
[image: Entire Window]

I want to be able to have the row(s) of data display not with a scroll-bar as seen above, but with TextWrapping as that would look much more visually appealing. (Keep in mind, all of these ItemSource's are in sync, so, each row of data goes hand-in-hand with eachother. )

ListView is not recognizing TextWrapping.Wrap; | is it that ListView is not able to use textwrapping?

Comment: When you say **in paragraph form** do you mean [`TextWrapping`?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping(v=vs.110).aspx) As I didn't see any paragraph formation in your data. Otherwise, you could check [`FlowDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant TextWrapping. Edited main post.

Comment: I suppose my question is more-so, can ListView use textwrapping or should I re-design my GUI to just handle textBlocks (As I know how to wrap those)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView does not recognize TextWrapping in WPF.
I went ahead and just re-modelled my interface in TextBlocks, then enabled textWrapping that way | Works the same, but instead of a list, individual data is displayed.